# Регулярное выражение (обратные ссылки)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, почему данное регулярное выражение `\b(\w+)\b \b\1\b` выделяет `two two` и `five five`, но не выделяет `six, six` и `seven. seven.` с разделителями в виде запятой и точки, несмотря на присутствие символа границы слова `\b`.

[image]

Ссылка на regexp: https://regex101.com/r/bGKAtL/1

Comment: У вас там явно задан пробел, Напишите так `\b(\w+)\b[\s,.]+\b\1\b` - выделит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробел не может найти запятую или точку.

Используйте

```
preg_match('~\b(\w+)\W+\1\b~u', $text, $matches)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/WHhDEC/2).

Главное отличие — шаблон `\W+`, который находит 1 и более символов, отличных от букв, цифр и некоторых других символов. Поддержка кириллицы осуществляется с помощью модификатора `u`.